# Can't change Customer Address Attribute visibility

Tags: attributes, frontend, customer-address

Any idea why these aren't editable? I just want the City to show under a specific store scope. I edited the template to only show the city then had problems with javascript validation. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: grey options]

Comment: It's Magrento Feature that once you create attribute then after you can not change the some feature as you mention in image

Comment: This only happens on certain ones, I think they may be part of the core of magento and cant be changed. This doesn't happen for attributes I created myself.

Comment: Particularly note the Show on Frontend and Forms to Use In are not selectable even in default scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

Magento has some attributes which are vital for a normal flow of core modules thus their editing is limited. These attributes are marked as `System`. You can see it in a `System` column in attributes grid.

Comment: I just ended up disabling this on that particular store view and creating new custom attributes. We still use it for the checkout but we dont need all of them on the registration form if theyre just creating an account, just the city/state so we know what region theyre covered by. Thanks for confirming as i couldnt find any documentation suggesting which were core attributes, but i suppose thats common sense